# Show that $ \frac{2+\ln a }{2}\lt\frac{a-1}{\ln a} \lt \frac{1+a}{2}$ becomes $ \frac{2(a-1)}{a+1}\lt\ln a \lt -1 + \sqrt{2a-1}$

Tags: inequality, intuition, integral-inequality

> Show that $\displaystyle \frac{2+\ln a }{2}\lt\frac{a-1}{\ln a} \lt \frac{1+a}{2}$ becomes $\displaystyle \frac{2(a-1)}{a+1}\lt\ln a \lt -1 + \sqrt{2a-1}$

The closest I can get is $$ \frac{2(a-1)}{a+1}\lt\ln a\lt\frac{2(a-1)}{2+\ln a}.$$ But I did this by flipping both sides and reversing the inequality, I lack the relevant knowledge to know if this was a valid move.

I've often been told off for not giving context to my questions so here it is - a STEP paper question:[image]

The first part i) I can solve and I already have a solution to the second part ii):

[image]

Was there any way of reaching that result without having to separate out the inequality? In other words can it be done by performing operations on both sides of $$ \frac{2(a-1)}{a+1}\lt\ln a\lt\frac{2(a-1)}{2+\ln a}.$$

Best regards,
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ln a < \frac{2(a-1)}{2+\ln a} <=> (\ln a)^2+2\ln a<2(a-1) <=> (\ln a)^2+2\ln a+1<2(a-1)+1 <=> (\ln a+1)^2<2a-1 => \ln a < \sqrt{2a-1}-1$,

Note that $\ln a$ is positive, for the above multiplication by $\ln a +2$, since $a$ is bigger than $1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, was there any way of reaching that result without having to separate out the inequality? In other words can it be done by performing operations on both sides of $$ \frac{2(a-1)}{a+1}\lt\ln a\lt\frac{2(a-1)}{2+\ln a}.$$

Comment: I don't see another way of arriving at the desired inequality from the one you posted above. One would have to do the same operations as done in the answer and that would alter the left hand side. As an extra advice, I would say that, rarely, in double inequalities one can operate on the both sides simultaneously.

Comment: Okay that's good enough for me, thanks for your answer and advice, regards.